# Line clamping using a class element and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a PHP script that outputs data. It is all conveniently wrapped inside a `p class`.

It outputs the same data and same class multiple times, so there are like 6 blocks of text, each block being wrapped inside `p class`.

I need to reduce each block to 3 lines using any method possible. I already tried using PHP in various ways to no avail.

I came across [Clamp.js](https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js) which looked great. The only issue is, it will only work using ID. I can change the `p class` tags to `p id`, however, they'd all have to share the same ID, which, obviously, won't work.

Here's the current code I've tried:

```
var module = document.getElementsByClassName("clampjs");

$clamp(module, {clamp: 1});
```

And the HTML (times 6):

```
<div class="headtab">
<a href="f?forum=(forum number)">Forum title</a><p class="bold">Posted By:</p> username <p class="bold">In:</p> category</div>
<div class="maintext">
<p class="clampjs">TEXT I WANT TO BE CLAMPED</p>
</div>
```

Like I say, it works fine when I use an ID, but obviously, only for the first block of text as the ID HAS to stay the same, that's why I'm using `p class`.

Sadly, what I've tried above doesn't work at all. Does anybody know a little fix for this script, or perhaps a different script that will clamp objects using a `class` element? Jquery is acceptable too.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqe4Ljdx/1/)

**Working code thanks to the accepted answer:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {   

     $('.clampjs').css({  //changes the css of the clicked content.
            'max-height':'75px', //give what ever height you want.
            'overflow':'hidden'
        });


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this could be easily done with just editing your css**

```
$('.clampjs').click( function() {   

     $(this).css({  //changes the css of the clicked content.
            'height':'100px', //give what ever height you want.
            'overflow':'hidden'
        });


    });
```

just now tested in my page it works...

Comment: It's so obvious now! Ideally, I'd have wanted to break it off at a certain line as your way can chop off the bottoms of letters, that's why I used the plugin, however I made a small edit to your code and voilá! It worked great (I added my code to my question)

Many thanks!